# Delete duplicate and some extra info in the same line

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have the below line like 40 thousands. only this '7zafop3n' varies.

```
[url]=http://filesflash.net/7zafop3n]http://filesflash.net/7zafop3n[/url]
```

I need the output as

```
http://filesflash.net/7zafop3n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How do I delete duplicate and some extra info in the same line

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `\[url=http://filesflash.net.*?\](.*)\[/url]`
- Set "Replace with" to `\1`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

Before:

```
[b][color=Red]Indian Natural Booby Nita[/color][/b]
[url=http://pzy.be/v/2/thumbs20130823073049.jpg][img]http://pzy.be/i/2/thumbs20130823073049.jpg[/img][/url]
[b][color=Blue]Download from anyone of the following link[/color][/b]
[url=http://filesflash.net/a2vlclvr]http://filesflash.net/a2vlclvr[/url]
```

After:

```
[b][color=Red]Indian Natural Booby Nita[/color][/b]
[url=http://pzy.be/v/2/thumbs20130823073049.jpg][img]http://pzy.be/i/2/thumbs20130823073049.jpg[/img][/url]
[b][color=Blue]Download from anyone of the following link[/color][/b]
http://filesflash.net/a2vlclvr
```

---

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)

Comment: Unfortunately, its not working.
https://regex101.com/r/1BMjC3/1

Comment: @StevenK Well it works here with your test string.

Comment: @StevenK Are you sure you string starts with `[url]=` and not `[url=`?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, it starts with [url=

Comment: @StevenK Answer updated. Do you need more help? If this answered your question, please don't forget to [accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: here is the sample script
************************************************************************
[b][color=Red]Indian Natural Booby Nita[/color][/b]
[url=http://pzy.be/v/2/thumbs20130823073049.jpg][img]http://pzy.be/i/2/thumbs20130823073049.jpg[/img][/url]
[b][color=Blue]Download from anyone of the following link[/color][/b]
[url=http://filesflash.net/a2vlclvr]http://filesflash.net/a2vlclvr[/url]

Comment: @ DavidYes, pyz.be image links also exist. It is updating image links too. But I need only flilesflash.net links to be updated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @StevenK Answer updated again. I'm not including your rude link in the test data. It has been deleted.